# Is there a way to check if comboBox Items are empty? C#

Tags: c#

So I have a comboBox that has text but no Items until you add them. I want to check if there are no Items in the comboBox without the Text having any effect upon checking the Items. I have tried this but it has no effect:

```
if (comboBox1.Items == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("no items in comboBox")
}
```

Comment: Yeah do `comboBox1.Items.Count == 0`. You should have done some google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `comboBox1.Items.Count` to count the number of comboboxes in the list:

```
if (comboBox1.Items.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("no items in comboBox")
}
```

Comment: Wow I could've swore I tried this... Thank you! Will accept as answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @KobiashiMaru Happy to help. Happy coding.